# Streamlined Adding and Replacing Fragments in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am working on a small App with just a few screens that I want to implement as a single Activity which calls several fragments. I have some experience in Java for Android but using Kotlin is new territory.
I have understood how to basically add fragments in Kotlin, but I'd like to do it in a reusable way.
I came across the solution mentioned [here](https://medium.com/thoughts-overflow/how-to-add-a-fragment-in-kotlin-way-73203c5a450b) and it works, but there is something I don't quite understand. My following MainActivity works so far, but I have to create the var welcomeFragment in the onCreate method like I did it here:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        var welcomeFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this@MainActivity,
                WelcomeFragment::class.java!!.getName())

        addFragment( welcomeFragment, welcome)

    }

    inline fun android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.inTransaction(func:               android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.() -> android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction) {
    beginTransaction().func().commit()
    }


    fun AppCompatActivity.addFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int){
        supportFragmentManager.inTransaction { add(frameId, fragment) }
    }

    fun AppCompatActivity.replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int) {
        supportFragmentManager.inTransaction{replace(frameId, fragment)}
    }




    }
```

I don't seem to get why I can't declare the property and later assign it. It's possible to declare it with lateinit but when I then try to assign it like this:

```
var welcomeFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this@MainActivity,
                WelcomeFragment::class.java!!.getName())
```

I get "Type mismatch - Required: Fragment, found: WelcomeFragment!"
Also, if I try to do this:

```
addFragment(WelcomeFragment, welcome)
```

Android Studio complains about WelcomeFragment ´(which is right now just empty except for a TextView saying "Welcome") not having a companion object. I have tried to make one but I don't really understand what it has to do. Reading the documentation didnt help me either with this one.

So my question is: How do I do the instantiating right, and or do I have to do it at all when most of my fragments will be one instance only. Can I avoid this by properly adding a companion object to my fragments? How would that look?

Any help on this, hints at misconceptions I have here, or general stupidity pointed out would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I spent a while now getting used to Kotlin, and I guess I just didn't get how to properly do these things when I asked this question. So by now I think it is not a useful question.

Answer (score 1):

Please be careful with the imports, sometimes we have a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` 
and then we can't use `android.app.Fragment.instantiate` function in it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? That I could get them mixed up? All my imports are of the android.support.v4.app.Fragment class.

Comment: "Type mismatch - Required: Fragment, found: WelcomeFragment!" is a typical error when trying to access Fragment.instantiate and passing another class. I just say it. I will try to reproduce your error